# How to force win10 to open virtual tablet keyboard?

Tags: c#, windows-10

I have an app that needs a virtual keyboard. But, when I click some of my `TextBox`es, they don't make the virtual keyboard appear. I have tried using this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

But this opens another keyboard, one that does not close after the `TextBox` has no focus. How to force win10 to open the virtual tablet keyboard?

To make myself clear:
This is running on a win10 touch screen PC. When I have the tablet mode enabled the virtual keyboard shows up on some `TextBox`es and does not on others. Hence why I want to force the keyboard to show.

**EDIT:**
I have since found a way to show the "virtual tablet keyboard", however I would like to do it using the  [InputPane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane) class. Can someone provide me with a example code just to get me started?

Code to open it **without** using the [InputPane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane) class:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("TabTip.exe");
```

Comment: Why do you want to force it? On desktop platform it is a bad practice, that's why it doesn't open. On tablets/phones the virtual keyboard will open because there is no other way for the user to enter characters .

Comment: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-force-tablet-mode-windows-10

Comment: Yes but he wants to do it programatically. Of course, if the user selected tablet mode the virtual keyboard will open. My point was that he can't force it to open. It will either open by default or the user can enable it if he wants.

Comment: I think he is saying that he doesn't want to force it, but sometimes the keyboard doesn't appear and the user can't input anything into the app, so he needs to force it in those cases. It seems like there is some event handler on the text box that is saying the event is handled so the keyboard never opens.

Comment: Edited the question with further explanation. =)

Comment: Really you should try to fix that problem before trying to manually open and close the keyboard (which is called the `InputPane`. [InputPane class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx) has information about the `InputPane` as well as the method you are looking for `TryShow` which shows the virtual keyboard.

Comment: I know it would be better and more correct. However i have searched in the events for something to cause this and there is nothing. And i kinda need this quick so i just prefer to hard code it for now. Can you point me to some tutorial to use InputPane?

Answer (score 2):

One thing. InputPane, you cannot use in WinForms, InputPane is a element of UWP.

I ran this code... And Works!

```
 string progFiles = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink";
 string keyboardPath = Path.Combine(progFiles, "TabTip.exe");
 Process.Start(keyboardPath);
```

But I had to add a key (MANUALLY) value on my regedit on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip` inside the key is a folder named 1.7 (this would change in the future by Microsoft) and add a 32 bit DWORD value named `EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke` with value `1`. This means TRUE. It should look like this:

[image: REGEDIT]

You can add the key programatically I think you need Admin privilegies. I tried add the key programatically but does not work, It double the entry without any effect (BE CAREFUL);

ADVICES:

Consider, do a process stopper for each process you create. I suposse that you will use this when textbox (ar any input method) request focus. be sure stop the process when component loses his focus.

hope this help.

[image]