# UWP - Open Windows Virtual Keyboard on Mouse Click

Tags: c#, uwp, virtual-keyboard

I have a UWP application which is run in tablet mode so when a user touches any textbox virtual keyboard gets open on the system, what I want is when a user clicks on textbox using Mouse then also virtual keyboard should open automatically.

Can anyone help regarding this?

Comment: I think this answers your question. See link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249607/how-to-force-win10-to-open-virtual-tablet-keyboard

Comment: We cannot use Process.Start in UWP application, we have already tried this.

Comment: May this class can help you.
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane      it has some methods like 1.GetForCurrentView 2.TryHide 3 TryShow

Comment: This class has 2 methods TryHide and TryShow, we have used TryHide to hide the keyboard programatically, but TryShow does not works same.

Comment: As far as I know there is no clear solution to this issue

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT is right, There is no way to do this.